# Best web media players for own website?

Tags: media, multiplayer

Custom control,simple,more features and plugins...

Comment: I don't get the close-vote for "not-programming-related". It's definitely about programming. It's the same type of question as "what's a good framework for this or that?".

Answer (score 2):

[Flowplayer](http://flowplayer.org/) is very good Flash video player. It comes in free and commercial version, and can be customized beyond your wildest dreams :)

Answer (score 2):

[JW FLV Media player, probably the best flash player around.](http://code.google.com/p/jw-flv-player/)

Answer (score 0):

One of the simplest MP3 players is [playtagger](http://delicious.com/help/playtagger) (see the two examples at the bottom of that page).

You simply include the js file, and a small play/stop button will be displayed next to every MP3 link. You have no possibility for customization, and it only works for MP3 (AFAIK). But it's very easy to use.